# View filter by date not current

Tags: views

I have two blocks on our Drupal 8 front page: one shows a list of events upcoming; the other a list of events past. The blocks are generated from views filtering nodes whose event dates are after and before today's date respectively (using an 'event date' field, not the date authored).  The granularity of the event dates is to an hour. The filter is set to compare to 'now'.

But ... the lists are rarely up to date, usually several days out in fact. With 'future' events having event dates of days recently passed.   So I'm not looking at caching as the source of the problem (rightly or wrongly) as we have cacheing configured in hours not days.

What can I do to ensure that the lists are correct each day?

Comment: `the lists are rarely up to date, usually several days out in fact` When you clear the cache does it fix?

Comment: Clearing the cache has no immediate effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Clearing the cache has no immediate effect.

Then it's very likely that is not a caching issue and it's a set up issue.

This should work, is greater than 0 minutes

[image]

Comment: Thanks @No Sweat - I had "offset from current time: now" (meaningless) rather than "offset from the current time: 0"